# Is there a conditional tag to determine whether the post is _any_ custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-tags

We know you can do `if ( is_singular( 'my-cpt' ) )` to test for a *specific* custom post type, but what about doing one thing if the post is a built-in post type, and another if it is not?

Is it enough to just test against `if ( is_singular() && ! is_singular( 'post' ) )`? Or are there some implications or subtleties that are escaping me at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a conditional tag, but here's how you would list the built-in types:

```
echo implode(',', get_post_types( array('_builtin' => true ) ) );
```

Output:

```
post,page,attachment,revision,nav_menu_item
```

Maybe better:

```
// 1 result if it exists and is builtin, 0 otherwise
get_post_types( array('_builtin' => true, 'name' => $post_type ) );
```

Comment: That's a great angle!